# Add a deployment administrator to CRM 4.0 using SQL

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm

Is there a way to add a deployment administrator to Microsoft CRM 4.0 using a sql query against the CRM database?  The person that setup the CRM was the only one who was the Deployment Administrator and he has left and his account was deactivated before another Deployment Administrator could be added using the deployment manager tool.  Or is there another way of adding another Deployment Administrator?

Comment: I take it you don't have a System Administrator account?

Comment: I am a member of the local system administrator for the vpc where the CRM is hosted.  But only the previous user who installed the CRM was added to the Deployment Administrator group within CRM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to set additional deployment administrators is through the "Deployment Manager" mmc console. Of course that the console must be opened under the existing deployment administrator AD account.

If you say that the account was disabled from the AD, then reenable it, reset the password to something you know and then open the console and add another Deployment Manager.

On the other hand, if the account was deactivated from CRM, than that means that another CRM user has the privilege to activate/deactivate users ... so log on with that user and reactivate the account.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to add a deployment administrator to Dynamics CRM 4.0 SQL. It is important that you setup at least two deployment administrators in the event that one account is deactivated.  The only option would be to reinstall CRM and then import the organization. In our case we were fortunate that we were able to have the deactivated account reactivated and we were able to add at least two deployment administrators in both the UAT and PROD environments.

In order to register a CRM plugin you need to be a CRM System Admin, Customizer and Deployment Administrator.